# How to convert text within R markdown chunk to italic when knitting to PDF

Tags: r, text, r-markdown, italic

I am trying to convert text within Rmarkdown chunk to italic such that italic appears in PDF after knitting.

So let's say I have for example the following chunk:

````
```{r}
"I want this text to be in italic when knitting"
                ```
````

How do I make the text appear in italic in PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can try LaTeX-solution:

Choose **xelatex** engine:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

*Italic*, **Bold** and ***Combined***:

```
\textit{I want this text to be in italic when knitting}

\textbf{I want this text to be in italic when knitting}

\textbf{\textit{I want this text to be in italic when knitting}}
```

[image]